# Stripe - How to get purchaser's information for a charge with Connect (Express)?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've set up a test charge using `stripe.Charge.create()` and it is working, i.e. I can see the dollar amounts processed in the Connect test dashboard. It appears to be money going from the tok_visa to a dummy Stripe account I set up.

```
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=1000,
  currency="usd",
  source="tok_visa",
  application_fee_amount=123,
  transfer_data={
    "destination": "{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
  }
)
```

For a marketplace type platform, I need to be able to send funds from the purchasing user to the selling user, however.

Would I need to get the purchaser's account (or some other object?) to use as the "source" in the charge?

How do I get that to put it into the "source" field?

I feel a little lost in Stripe's docs, so I could be missing something. Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to send funds from the purchasing user to the
>   selling user, however

If by 'purchasing user' you mean a cardholder customer of your marketplace, this is exactly what you have. `tok_visa` here represents a credit card, that you accept through a payment page.

If instead you mean, the purchasing user is another connected account in the marketplace, you can either :

- use an [account debit](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits) to debit one account, and then [transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create) to
  another.
- collect a card from users when they sign up and [create a
  Customer object for them](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards). You can then charge that customer as needed
  like in your example code. You need to maintain a link in your system that
  'customer `cus_xxx` is also my marketplace user `acct_xxx`'